# Eclipse: load Codetemplates from XML File during startup

Tags: eclipse, code-templates

How do I setup Eclipse to load the Codetemplates from an XML-File instead of the INI-File?

By default, Eclipse stores its Codetemplates in a nearly unreadable single-line format in an INI-File.

Is it possible to point Eclipse to an external "codetemplates.xml"-File that is loaded during startup?

Thanks,
VanDahlen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about the Java code templates there is no way to do this.

The code which loads the templates (`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProjectTemplateStore`) always loads from the Java UI plugin preferences.

The only access to external files is through the Import and Export buttons on the code templates preference page.

Comment: Too bad. Do you know about CDT, too?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use CDT.